# Reformulation in linear programming with $\max_i \ a_i^Tx + b_i$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I was reading about the following *trick* in convex analysis. Consider the (not obvious) LP

$$p = \max_i \ a_i^Tx + b_i$$

but apparently it can be equivalently reformulated as an LP:

$$ \min_{x,t} \ t, \quad s.t. \ a_i^Tx + b_i \leq t$$

---

Now, I cannot figure out how you go from one into the other. Isn't $p = \lVert Ax + b \rVert_\infty$?

Also, I am not even sure what the index $i$ in $\max_i$ is supposed to mean - searching an index in a matrix $A$ and vector $b$ that maximizes $a_i^Tx + b_i$?

Comment: $i$ is  indexing the columns of $A$. For each $i$, $a_i^Tx + b_i$ is just the $i$th component of the vector $Ax  + b$. Finally, $\|Ax + b\|_\infty := \max_i |a_i^T + b_i| \ne p := \max_i a_i^Tx + b_i$.

Comment: You original LP is $max_{i}a_{i}^{\intercal}x+b_{i}$, so you fixed $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a finite number of reals $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n$. For any other real number $t$, the following 2 conditions are equivalent:

*(a)* The largest of the $r_i$'s is not bigger than $t$.

*(b)* Neither of the $r_i$'s is bigger than $t$.

Thus, the smallest $t$ satisfying condition *(b)* is precisely the largest of the $r_i$'s, that is,
$$\max\{r_i | i=1,2,\ldots,n\} = \min\{t | r_1 \le t, r_2 \le t, \ldots, r_n\le t\}.$$