# Some questions about the max-min optimization problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

The author of a optimization paper states this:

> maximizing the minimum value of a function over the index set is
>   equivalent to minimizing a parameter subject to the negative of all
>   functional values over the index set being smaller than or equal to
>   $\underset{\textbf{u}}{\text{max}}\ \underset{t\in \Omega}{\text{min}}
> \ f(t,\textbf{u})$, that is is equivalent to
>    $\underset{\textbf{u}}{\text{min}\ v }$ subject to $-f(t,\textbf{u})
>  \leq v ,\forall t\in \Omega$

Could anyone help me out why this transformation problme is valid?

---

Another trasnformation problem: 
$\text{min}\ J =  \underset{a}{\text{max}}\left (\underset{b}{\text{max}}\ y(t) - \underset{b}{\text{min}}\ y(t)\right ) $

Its transformation is equal to : $$\text{min}\ J =  \alpha_1v_1 + \alpha_2v_2 $$

$$s.t.\ y(t) \leq v_1  \ \forall t\text{ satisfy a and b}$$
$$\ \ \ \ -y(t) \leq v_2  \ \forall t\text{ satisfy a and b}$$

I do not know how this transformation forms. Why two different scalars? Could you help?

Comment: My answer to this question answers you main question too https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2206490/168758.

Comment: @dohmatob Thanks for your reply. You answered the **min-max** problem in that question, but not **max-min** that I want

Comment: The arguments should be completely **ANALOGOUS**.